# Can not export function

Tags: node.js, express, promise, es6-promise

I try use function:

```
exports.get = async function (req, res, next) {
  filter.validateId(req,res,next);
  const db = req.app.get('db');
  let id = req.params.id;
  let user;
  try {
    user = await db.models.user.findByPk(id);
  } catch (err) {
    res.send(400)
  }
  res.json(user);
};
```

and exported function:

```
var validateId = function (req, res, next) {
  let id = parseInt(req.params.id);
  if (isNaN(id) || id <= 0) {
      res.send(400);
  }
  res.locals.id = id;

  return next();
};
exports.validateId=validateId;
```

But I got error:

GET /users/203 404 17.862 ms - 90

> (node:20775) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
>       at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:470:11)
>       at ServerResponse.header (/home/qt/dev/BigDealExpressJSTest/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:767:10)
>       at ServerResponse.send (/home/qt/dev/BigDealExpressJSTest/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:170:12)
>       at ServerResponse.json (/home/qt/dev/BigDealExpressJSTest/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:267:15)
>       at exports.get (/home/qt/dev/BigDealExpressJSTest/controllers/userController.js:28:7)
>   (node:20775) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
>   (node:20775) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: The error `Cannot set headers after they are sent` is because you are sending a response twice, probably on `validateId` first and later  with `res.json(user)`

Comment: ok, I fix if, but now i got error  `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:21582) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
`

Answer (score 1):

THis is wrong for couple of reasons:

**First:**

```
if (isNaN(id) || id <= 0) {
      res.send(400); //return res.send(400);
}
```

need to add `return` so that even after sending the response `next()` is not called.

**Now for the real reason:**

In `validateId` you are passing `get` function's `next`. So whenever you call next from `validateId` you are actually calling `next` of `get` thus sending the control to next middleware.

So you need to remove the `filter.validateId(req,res,next);` line from `get` function and add it as a second middlware.

ie.

```
exports.get = async function (req, res, next) {
  const db = req.app.get('db');
  let id = req.params.id;
  let user;
  try {
    user = await db.models.user.findByPk(id);
  } catch (err) {
    res.send(400)
  }
  res.json(user);
};
```

`app.get('/route', validateId, get , (req,res)=>{.. do something })`
or
`app.get('/route', validateId, get)`